# Oracle Application - Mask a specific field for a specific set of users

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I'm using OA release 12, what I'm trying to do without success is to mask in a form a field (for example all the words or code in that column with this string "######") but only for a specific set of users for privacy and safety reasons. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it using below query.

```
SELECT info1, NVL2(user_name, info2, '######') info2
  FROM your_info_table b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       your_app_user_with_access a
   ON (user_name = var_pkg.get_logged_user);
/
```

or you can also create a view from that query, see below sample

```
CREATE TABLE app_user_with_access
(user_name VARCHAR2(20));
/

INSERT INTO app_user_with_access
VALUES
('USER2');
/

INSERT INTO app_user_with_access
VALUES
('USER1');
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE var_pkg
IS
    logged_user VARCHAR2(10);
    PROCEDURE set_logged_user(p_logged_user VARCHAR2);
    FUNCTION get_logged_user RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY var_pkg
IS
    PROCEDURE set_logged_user(p_logged_user VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        logged_user := p_logged_user;
    END;
    FUNCTION get_logged_user RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN logged_user;
    END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE info_table
(info1 VARCHAR2(10), info2 VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO info_table
(info1, info2)
VALUES
('Info Info', 'InfoHide');

CREATE VIEW info_view
AS
select info1, NVL2(user_name, info2, '######') info2
  from info_table b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
       app_user_with_access a
   ON (user_name = var_pkg.get_logged_user);
 /
```

Using the view:

```
 BEGIN
    var_pkg.set_logged_user('USER');
 END;
 /

SELECT * FROM info_view;

Output:

INFO1      INFO2    
---------- ----------
Info Info  ######    

 BEGIN
     var_pkg.set_logged_user('USER1');
 END;
 /

SELECT * FROM info_view;

Output:

INFO1      INFO2    
---------- ----------
Info Info  InfoHide
```